Admin area in Rails (separated namespaces)
I’m very new to Rails. I set myself a task to create super-simple site with the following:
Authorized Admin Area Place to Add/Edit/Update ‘Pages’ (With Slug and Body). Output said pages to non-auth’d users.
Pretty simple but covers some fundamentals outside of the usual blog demo.
The trickiest bit so far is using a generator to generate things inside of a namespaced area.
So for example, I’ve created a Model called pages (that sits in /models). I then want to do the CRUD for this inside the Admin namespace.
So the routes look like this:
 namespace :admin do
    resources :pages, constraints: { format: :html }
  end

Now, whenever I generate a controller or view using the generators, it’s constantly struggling to find routes
undefined method `page_path'

Being the common error.
Am I expecting too much from the generators here, is creating a namespaced area against the Rails conventions? How do you structure Admin areas (or just logged in areas) inside a Rails app?

This question is similar to: How to generate controller inside namespace in rails. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@dbugger while it's somewhat similar I think the issue here is that the code is generated with rails g controller admin/pages while the model is at the top level namespace instead of nested in the Admin module. The code generated doesn't quite work off the bat in that case.

just get list of available routes with rails routes on the console, and probably you will see admin_page as route helper

Max is right, the question is about using the generators and if it's appropriate, not how to use them.
Anton, yea I'm aware and the example above is working but was checking in on the overriding the output of the generators.

You may be expecting a bit too much.
The Rails generators only work for namespaced resources when the model is in the same module as the "namespace".
So for example when you run rails g scaffold admin/pages it will generate the model as:
class Admin::Page < ApplicationRecord
end

And since the module is included in the model name:
irb(main):001:0> Admin::Page.model_name
=>
#<ActiveModel::Name:0x000055caa5f6f958
 @collection="admin/pages",
 @element="page",
 @human="Page",
 @i18n_key=:"admin/page",
 @klass=Admin::Page (call 'Admin::Page.connection' to establish a connection),
 @name="Admin::Page",
 @param_key="admin_page",
 @plural="admin_pages",
 @route_key="admin_pages",
 @singular="admin_page",
 @singular_route_key="admin_page",
 @uncountable=false>

It just works with the generated views/controller such as this:
<%= link_to "Show this page", @admin_page %> 

As it will derive the route helper method admin_page_path which is what your routes generate as namespace prefixes the route helpers.
If your Page class is instead just at the top level namespace you instead get undefined method 'page_path' as it will derive that helper name. Fixing the issue is as easy as passing an array instead:
<%= link_to "Show this page", [:admin, @admin_page] %> 

Or explicitly calling the route helper:
<%= link_to "Show this page", admin_page_path(@admin_page) %> 

However the code templates are not really sophisticated enough so you'll have to do quite a bit of fixing after the fact. If you're doing this a lot you can customize the generators or code templates.

Am I expecting too much from the generators here, is creating a namespaced area against the Rails conventions?

Not really. The code templates are really just for rapid prototyping of easy scenarios and don't quite cover every possible scenario or even generate decent code that passes linting with Rubucop. I would just view them as a jumping off point that's meant to be modified.
There are plenty of things that would still be considered within the conventions such as nested resources but that can't be generated with generators.

How do you structure Admin areas (Or just logged in areas) inside a Rails app?

Namespacing your route/controller has very little to do with implementing that feature. It's really just a way of organizing your routes and code.
To create a restricted area in your application you're most likely going to need authentication to be able to identify users and authorization to restrict what the user can do. This is not something that's built into Rails.
There is no single solution for this problem and it's really up to you as programmer to find what works best for your requirements. Devise and Pundit are popular choices.

Max, first off, it's been a while since I've been to Stackoverflow, thank you for taking the time to write this out.
It affirms all of my expectations, I just wanted to be super careful in Rails as I've been warned to make sure I do things the 'Rails Way'.
Once again, thank you for the time in putting this together.

I wouldn't worry to much about it. If you follow the Ruby style guide and the naming conventions for Rails and read the guides for routing you'll be perfectly fine. Rubocop is your friend here. If anything beginers tend to go a bit overboard and try to find "the Rails Way" or [shudder] "Best Practice" in absurdum.

When generating controller you can override the model to use unnamespaced name:
bin/rails g model page title body:text
bin/rails g scaffold_controller admin/page title body:text --model-name=page

